# Left hand side vertical scrollbar for a WPF DataGrid: Column widths do not fill correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have two wpf DataGrids side by side showing different sides of market orders.

[image]

I have been able to move the vertical scrollbar in the DataGrid on the left hand side to the left using a style with a control template for the ScrollViewer.

The last datagrid column width is set to * so that the columns fill all the available space and the horizontal scrollbar should never appear.

This works correctly when the scrollbars are not visible and when the right side vertical scrollbar is visible.

The problem is that the datagrid columns do not fill the available space correctly when the vertical scrollbar is visible on the left hand side DataGrid.

The last column get shortened by the width of the scrollbar and it appears that an empty extra column is place beside it.

[image]

Here is the style that I am using:

```
        <Style x:Key="leftScrollbar" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="Collapsed"/>               
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">

                                        <Grid>

                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <ScrollBar 
                                                x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" 
                                                Grid.Column="0" 
                                                Grid.Row="1" 
                                                Orientation="Vertical" 
                                                Width="10"
                                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"                                                                                                         
                                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                                Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>

                                            <ScrollContentPresenter 
                                                x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                Grid.Column="1" 
                                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                                Grid.Row="1"
                                                CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" 
                                                />

                                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter 
                                                x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" 
                                                Grid.Column="2" 
                                                Grid.Row="0"
                                                Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                                Background="#00FFFFFF" 
                                                FontSize="10.5"/>

                                            <Grid 
                                                Grid.Column="2" 
                                                Grid.Row="2">

                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" 
                                                           Grid.Column="1" 
                                                           Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" 
                                                           Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                                           Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                                           Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                                           ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>                                
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column">
                    <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Your first `DataGrid` column header needs to be margined when the left scroll bar becomes visible. It's remaining in place which is causing all your columns to shift, but not the header. You will probably have to edit the header's style in the datagrid to handle this. I would see how the header behaves when the right vertical scrollbar becomes visible for reference.

Comment: I thought at first that it might have been related to the first column but after measuring the the columns before and after it seems that the first column width remains the same. The last column "Bid" gets shortened by the width of the scrollbar and the extra column width. After looking at the source code for the datagrid I think it might have something to do with internal datagrid calculations when the internal scrollviewer is visible.